# Remove Items in a listbox, data taken from the check box

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, listbox

I'm doing some experiments lately but I can't make this one work. Here's my code:

```
If cbHistory.Checked = True Then
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\" & userName & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\UserData")
    Dim diar1 As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim dra As FileInfo

'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each dra In diar1
    listToDelete.Items.Add(dra)            
    Next
End If
```

My code takes a the list of files located in the specified location and put it in a list box. I have 2 more block of code like that (cbCache and cbCookies).

Now my problem is, I want that if I unchecked one of them, the cbHistory checkbox for example, it will remove the items it took from the directory. Now, I can't use listbox.items.clear() because it will remove everything in the list box. So what can I do here?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: is `listToDelete` actually a `CheckedListBox`?

Comment: The easiest way is to just clear the list box and repopulate with the code from the other two check boxes again.

Comment: No sir @Plutonix, its a normal listbox.

Comment: I tried that Sir @LarsTech but it's too time consuming. And I'm looking if theres some easier way to do this.

Comment: Then hold a reference to those items in a dictionary, clear the listbox, add the items from the dictionary items.  Something like `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of FileInfo))`.  The key would be the name of the CheckBox control.

Comment: Have you tried anything involving listbox.Items.Remove(str) or listbox.Items.RemoveAt(listbox.Items.IndexOf(str)?